# io_service not stopping after calling executor_work_guard::reset

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I'm fairly new to boost asio and trying to get the clean exit after calling the work_gaurd reset function. Below is the code i'm trying to get it working. However i'm not able to get the print of "IO Context Stopped"

Is there anything i'm missing here?

```
int main() {
  boost::asio::io_context ioContext;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  auto work = boost::asio::make_work_guard(ioContext);                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  ioContext.post([]() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    std::cout << "Task executed on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id()                                                                                                                                                                                 
              << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  std::thread ioThread([&ioContext]() { ioContext.run(); });                                                                                                                                                                                               
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  work.reset();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  //! ioContext.stop();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  ioThread.join();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  std::cout << "IO context stopped." << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine (even though the work-guard is completely redundant here):

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ee0338f0657c7bb)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioContext;

    auto work = make_work_guard(ioContext);
    post(ioContext, [] { std::cout << "Task executed on thread" << std::endl; });

    std::thread ioThread([&] { ioContext.run(); });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    work.reset();

    ioThread.join();
    std::cout << "IO context stopped." << std::endl;
}
```

Tested with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && time ./a.out
```

Prints e.g.

```
Task executed on thread
IO context stopped.

real    0m2,004s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,004s
```

### BONUS

Note that the result is [the same without the guard](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09cc74bb452f47c9). Even simpler is to use `thread_pool` which implies a work-guard:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c512babefe9cbb3)**

```
int main() {
    {
        boost::asio::thread_pool ioContext(1);
        post(ioContext, [] { std::cout << "Task executed on thread" << std::endl; });
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
        // ioContext.join();
    }

    std::cout << "IO context stopped." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can edit the live demos to find what is the thing you differently. E.g. what would cause everything to block is when the posted task blocks: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e495f8eaa8df868

Comment: If i remove ```std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);```, then your code also get stuck. Is there any reason for the sleep

Comment: It was your sleep. I assumed you wanted it to represent something else. Let me check for the repro though

Comment: Nope that doesn't reproduce, you could have verified this yourself too - which is why I suggested editing the online reproducer to rule out other code/circumstances you're not showing: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56235141fa7bb77b and even https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebe2337e3b3f8a9f

Comment: i figured out that when i have BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS flag enabled, the program is stuck forever otherwise it is working properly. Any reason why above stops the execution? @sehe

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93cde24236fbbebd for the reference

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. Your Coliru link makes no sense at all (you #define AFTER including all boost headers; even if **did** do that correctly you would still just confirm that `thread_pool` requires threads: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f31d4e9064ba8db. But yeah, if you it correctly if reproduces your error:  https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5830c7ffecd62fee

Comment: It's your errror because you tell Asio that there will not BE multiple threads, but then you notify the executor that work is finished from another thread. Because you instructed Asio that it [need not use atomics to track shared counters](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/detail/atomic_count.hpp#L33), it will never see the change and will keep running. (Actually, you have a data-race and that constitutes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))

Comment: Fixes: [1] don't lie to Asio about disabling thread support [2] [don't use threads](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbf4c493f6cf4dc4),